# CNN-based 1-D signal classification using Caffe

Tags: speech, caffe

I am looking for an easy and straightforward example of 1-D signal classification (such as speech signal) based on CNN using Caffe.

From the [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) website, it is possible to follow some examples and tutorial which are Image classification tasks. Instead, I am looking for an example and tutorial on 1-D signals.

Your answers are really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually there's no meaningful difference between working with 1D data vs 2D data. You'd need a database where instead of 2D images you'll have 1D "images" of shape (channels: 1, height: 1, width: d), and make sure all kernels make use of *kernel_w* and *kernel_h* instead of *kernel_size* (which sets the kernel to a square shape).

If you're looking for an example architecture you can use, there's this article you can follow for training a CNN on raw waveform speech data: [Speech Acoustic Modeling from Raw Multichannel Waveforms](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ydidh/waveform.pdf).

There's also [an open issue on Caffe's Github page](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1570) requesting an example for the speech domain, with more links to potential implementations you can look at.